unable to exit program when I free my array
I was working on a challenge in Chapter 14 of Crafting Interpreters. The main goal of this challenge is to implement a run-length encoding for the line numbers. like use 1 * 4 to represent 1 1 1 1.
lines.c
#include "lines.h
#include "memory.h
void writeLines(LinesArray* array,Line line){
   
    if(array->capacity < array->count + 1){
        int oldCapacity = array->capacity;
        array->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(oldCapacity);
        array->lines = GROW_ARRAY(Line,array->lines,oldCapacity,array->capacity);
    }
   
    if(array->count == 0){
        array->lines[array->count] = line;
        array->count++;
        array->lines[array->count] = 1;
    }else{
        
        if(array->lines[array->count - 1] == line){
            array->lines[array->count]++;
           
        }else{
            array->count++;
            array->lines[array->count] = line;
            array->count++;
            array->lines[array->count] = 1;
        }
    }
   
}

void freeLines(LinesArray* array){
    FREE_ARRAY(Line,array->lines,array->capacity);
    initLines(array);
}



and lines.h
#ifndef clox_lines_h
#define clox_lines_h
typedef int Line;
typedef struct{
    int capacity;
    int count;
    Line* lines;
}LinesArray;
void initLines(LinesArray* array);
void writeLines(LinesArray* array,Line line);
void freeLines(LinesArray* array);
Line getLine(LinesArray* array,int index);
#endif

then memory.h
#ifndef clox_memory_h
#define clox_memory_h

#include "common.h"


#define GROW_CAPACITY(capacity) \
    ((capacity) < 8 ? 8 : (capacity) * 2)


// The macro itself takes care of getting the size of the array’s element type and casting the resulting void* back to
// a pointer of the right type
#define GROW_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount, newCount) \
    (type*)reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type) * (oldCount), \
                      sizeof(type) * (newCount))


#define FREE_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount) \
    reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type) * (oldCount), 0)

void* reallocate(void* pointer, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize);

#endif

memory.c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "memory.h"
void * reallocate(void *pointer , size_t oldSize , size_t newSize){
    if(newSize == 0){
        free(pointer);
        return NULL;
    }
   

  
    void* result = realloc(pointer,newSize);
  
    if(result == NULL) exit(1);
    return result;
}

and my main
#include "../lines.h"
#include "../memory.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    LinesArray array;
    initLines(&array);
    writeLines(&array,1);
    writeLines(&array,1);
    writeLines(&array,1);
    writeLines(&array,2);
    writeLines(&array,2);
    writeLines(&array,3);
    writeLines(&array,3);
    writeLines(&array,3);
    writeLines(&array,4);
    writeLines(&array,5);
    int length = array.count;
    freeLines(&array);
    printf("demo\n");
    return 0;
}

the problem I encounter is when I free the array , more specific is lines in the struct , the program was stuck in there , it can't exit and can't go on like print demo. So why?

At least int size = sizeof(array->lines) / sizeof(int); is wrong, because sizeof(array->lines) is a sizeof Line* - i.e. a size of a pointer, not the length of the array, here int size will always be 1 or 2 regardless of the array's length. Btw, have you tried to run it under debugger, step by step?

This line you definitely want to change: if(result == NULL) exit(1); .  In general, you do not want to write library functions which will cause the calling process to exit entirely.  Instead, do if(result == NULL) return NULL.  Also, you will want to check the return value of GROW_ARRAY, to ensure it didn't return NULL, otherwise you could end up de-referencing a NULL pointer.

@Renat , I know the issue now , thanks. this is the first time I really write a big program , before that , i'm using simple way like use printf() , and I'm going to learning debug , thanks

@AndyJ I think when result == NULL ,this indicates that the resource heap is about to be exhausted, and the inability to allocate new space means the program cannot proceed, so I think this is why exit(1) is used. And author of the book "crafting interpreters" has write why he use exit or not return null : "There’s not really anything useful that our VM can do if it can’t get the memory it needs, but we at least detect that and abort the process immediately instead of returning a NULL pointer and letting it go off the rails later."

@user22873067 Logging error/notifying about out of memory before crashing & burning is one thing it can do.

Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

@TobySpeight Can you give me some examples of the peripheral parts, like the init() function or getLine()? Should I just show write(), free(), and memory() since they are the most important for my question?

OK, I think I found my mistake. The key is in lines.c/writeLines(). The growth condition is capacity < count + 1, but my count increases like 1, 3, 5, 7. When it reaches 7, the array should grow because we've reached the end of the array. Therefore, it should be "<=" instead of "<".
